# When will Sharepoint stop using webforms?

Tags: sharepoint-online

.Net Core doesn't uses webforms at all anymore; will Sharepoint use ASP.MVC also instead of webforms in the future? When will the new version of Sharepoint be launched?

Best regards,
Ion

Comment: Take a look at the new SharePoint Framework for SharePoint online. It leverages modern web technologies! SharePoint 2016 and Feature Pack 1 has launched last year.

Answer (score 2):

Since July 2013 it has been possible to choose MVC over WebForms when creating SharePoint add-ins:

> Apps are essentially web applications. If you know how to build a web
>   application, you know how to build an app for SharePoint. Prior to
>   Visual Studio 2013 Preview, you were able to create apps for
>   SharePoint with an ASP.NET Web Forms project application. Now, in
>   Visual Studio 2013 Preview, you can choose between ASP.NET Web Forms
>   and ASP.NET MVC for your project application.

[Introducing MVC support for apps for SharePoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/07/09/introducing-mvc-support-for-apps-for-sharepoint/)

But MVC isn't a 1-1 replacement for ASP.NET WebForms, and through several recent conferences Microsoft keeps telling us they won't change the core of SharePoint. Current SharePoint 2016 is derived from SharePoint Online, even though it's very similar to SharePoint 2013.

SharePoint vNext (supposedly 2019) hasn't got an official release date yet, and it'll probably be announced in the next year 2018 if Microsoft follows its recent announcement pattern.

However, Microsoft now develops SharePoint in the cloud which they will keep on deriving as a server version in something called feature pack.

> When we launched SharePoint Server 2016, we shared our vision that it
>   would be a foundational release, **born in the cloud and built for
>   continuous innovation**. Today, we’re pleased to announce our next step
>   on this journey with the availability of Feature Pack 1.

[Feature Pack 1 for SharePoint Server 2016 now available](https://blogs.office.com/2016/11/08/feature-pack-1-for-sharepoint-server-2016-now-available/)

Even though it's impossible to answer when, if ever, WebForms will be discontinued - we can be certain it'll be announced at least two years before support ends. Just as with the public facing website of SharePoint Online. So you can safely continue to develop WebForms for SharePoint. It ain't going away sometime soon.